# sum and division of sum of columns inside Pandas group by agg

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to do pandas groupby and aggregate.
I have sum of two columns and I also need the division of sum of two columns.

```
tdf = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {
        'app' : 'A',
         'num_requests'    : 100,
         'sum_resp_time' : 50000
        },
        {
        'app' : 'A',
         'num_requests'    : 50,
         'sum_resp_time' : 40000
        },
        {
        'app' : 'A',
         'num_requests'    : 70,
         'sum_resp_time' : 8000
        },
        {
        'app' : 'B',
         'num_requests'    : 100,
         'sum_resp_time' : 3000
        },
        {
        'app' : 'B',
         'num_requests'    : 10,
         'sum_resp_time' : 2000
        },
        {
        'app' : 'C',
         'num_requests'    : 1000,
         'sum_resp_time' : 500000
        },
        {
        'app' : 'C',
         'num_requests'    : 120,
         'sum_resp_time' : 52000
        }
    ]
)

(
    tdf 
    .groupby
    (        
        ['app']
    ) 
    .agg 
    ( 
        { 
            'num_requests' : ['sum'],             
            'sum_resp_time' : ['sum'],
            #'average_resp_time' : lambda x : x['sum_resp_time'].sum()  / x['num_requests'].sum()
        } 
    )

)
```

How can I get the 'average_resp_time' working , currently it is commented out.
My current average calculation throws error.

Answer (score 1):

This is your `groupby`

```
grouped = tdf.groupby(['app']).agg({'num_requests':'sum', 'sum_resp_time':'sum'})
```

To create `average_resp_time` column, just do:

```
grouped['average_resp_time'] = grouped['sum_resp_time'] / grouped['num_requests']

    num_requests    sum_resp_time   average_resp_time
app         
A   220     98000   445.454545
B   110     5000    45.454545
C   1120    552000  492.857143
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed out axis = 1.

```
df2['average_resp_time' ] = df2.apply(lambda x : x['sum_resp_time'].sum() / x['num_requests'], axis =1)
```